# Can I get a list of helpful hints during the load screen for Path of the Exile

Tags: path-of-exile

Can someone please list all the tips that appear during the loading screen?

I saw one about skill gems last night that I wanted to read but disappeared to quickly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Here is a list of all of the loading screen tips:

- Remember to use flasks (1-5 on the keyboard).
- You can remove a {Skill Gem} from an item by right clicking on it.
- Put a # before your chat message to talk globally.
- Instances reset after being empty for 15 minutes.
- Drop an item in the chat box to link it to other players.
- Players in the same party will join the same instances.
- Right click on a player or message them in chat to invite them to your party.
- Support gems need to be placed in linked sockets to affect another gem.
- Hold {Shift} to attack from your current location.
- You can access your stash in town.
- Waypoints can be used to travel quickly between some areas.
- Flasks on your belt refill as you kill enemies.
- Remember to allocate your passive skill points on the passives screen.
- To reach the next difficulty level, find the exit at the end of the current difficulty.
- To use a {scroll} or {orb}, right click it then left click the target item.
- Hold {Shift} and click a stack of items to unstack them.
- Never tell anyone your password.
- Some items need to be {identified} with a {Scroll of Wisdom} before they can be used.
- Cruel, Ruthless and Merciless difficulties incur an experience penalty on death.
- {Skill Gems} gain experience as you do while they are equipped.
- {Bosses} and {rare} monsters are more likely to drop powerful equipment.
- If you cannot use a gem, placing it in an item will stop you from using the item.
- Partying with other players makes enemies harder and rewards better.
- Don't let enemies surround you.
- You can change your key bindings in the {Options} menu.
- You can move the minimap around using the {arrow keys}.
- Your stash can be used to move items between your characters.
- Being polite will get you invited back to play with people again!
- There will be bugs.
- You can only remove or place Flasks in your belt while your inventory is open.
- Some chests have a better chance of dropping items than others.
- Monsters that deal cold damage can freeze you.
- Lightning damage can shock you, increasing damage taken.
- Fire damage can ignite targets, causing them to burn for extra damage.
- Holding Alt will show items on the ground, and pressing Z will toggle always displaying 
  items and sockets.
- Some containers can be opened by attacking them.
- Monsters with the very rare "Wealth" mod drop a huge number of items.
- Activating a new {Waypoint} is a way of saving your exploration through Wraeclast.
- At vendors, you can trade an Iron Ring and a Skill Gem for a resistance ring.